# Django Statelessness

Tags: django

I was reading some blogs and came up to the conclusion that django is an MVT architecture which do not maintain state. I am working on application that have maps visualization. When the user selects a variable from the drop down, a request is sent to the backend database and on the screen, it generates the heat-map of that specific variable.

what I want to achieve is that if I go some other tab and do some other changes like change the layer of map or select some another variable, the state of old heat map should be maintained regardless if I want to clear it. I do not know how to maintain state in django can anyone help me in this?

Comment: "the state of old heat map should be maintained regardless if I want to clear it" could you explain what you mean by "old heatmap" ? do you mean, on the first tab in your example ?

Comment: Exactly I mean on the first tab of my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the Django's [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/) mechanism. You'll need an AJAX request that `POST`s the current tab state to Django, so your backend code can restore it on page reload.